# how to update from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

I need to update the "ivalue" where mfieldid =33
based on the ivalue where mfieldid =44 for each respid
exmple:

for respid = 1 should updated 'gfgd' instead '12345'

```
+--------+----------+------------+
| respid | mfieldid |   ivalue   |
+--------+----------+------------+
|      1 |       33 | 12345      |
|      1 |       44 | gfgd       |
|      2 |       33 | 54353453   |
|      2 |       44 | treterttre |
|      3 |       33 | 5454       |
|      3 |       44 | tgbg       |
|      4 |       33 | 5443333    |
|      4 |       44 | bcvbcv     |
+--------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE t33
SET iValue=t44.iValue
--SELECT *
FROM Table t33
INNER JOIN Table t44 ON t33.respid = t44.respid
   AND t33.mfieldid=33
   AND t44.mfieldid=44
```